# What event to use when pasting something in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField`. I want an event to execute when I paste something inside the `JTextField`. What event do I need to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

Agree with Maroun Maroun about `KeyListener`

On paste use `DocumentListener with insertUpdate` method, like

```
 private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        Document document = e.getDocument();
        try {

            String s = document.getText(0, document.getLength());


        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
}
```

To add listener:

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) **doesn't** work if you paste in text, that's why you should use [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Check the link, it explains it very good, here's something to begin with:

```
private DocumentListener myListener = new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
        //...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: you are right, should be `MyDocumentListener` with  `insertUpdate`

Comment: when I scan a barcode using a barcode reader is it considered a paste?